# Incomplete word

Tags: vocabulary

This is in an astronomy book from 1672. I would need help please identifying the word that ends the second line and begins the third. There seems to be a misprint and a word missing its beginning but ending in “isdem.”

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word seems to be *iisdem*. (Ricciolus avails himself of the same etc.) Not much of it appears to be missing.

Comment: Oh! Great! Thank you. I was thrown off by the large spacing before, by the fact that I didn’t know this word, by the fact that I didn’t even think that a word could begin by two successive “i”s, and by the fact that the top left of the first “I” seems to be missing.

Comment: @PierrePaquette yes, a part of the 'I' appears to be missing from the print or scan.